# Python regex optional capture group or lastindex

Tags: python, regex, capture-group

I'm searching a file line by line for sections and sub sections using python.

```
   *** Section with no sub section
  *** Section with sub section ***
           *** Sub Section ***
  *** Another section
```

Sections start with 0-2 spaces followed by three asterisk, sub sections have 2+ white spaces then asterisks.

I write out the sections / sub sections without "***'s"; currently (using re.sub).

```
Section: Section with no sub section
Section: Section with sub section
Sub-Section: Sub Section
Section: Another Section
```

**QUESTION 1**: Is there a python regexp with capture groups that would let me access the section/sub section names as a capture group?

**QUESTION 2**: How would the regexp groups allow me to ID section or sub section (possibly based on the number of /content in a match.group)?

**EXAMPLE (NON WORKING):**

```
match=re.compile('(group0 *** )(group1 section title)(group2 ***)')
sectionTitle = match.group(1)
if match.lastindex = 0: sectionType = section with no subs
if match.lastindex = 1: sectionType = section with subs
if match.lastindex = 2: sectionTpe = sub section
```

**PREVIOUS ATTEMPTS**
I have been able to capture sections or sub sections with separate regexps and if statements, but I want to do it all at once.  Something like the line below; has trouble with the second groups greediness.

```
'(^\*{3}\s)(.*)(\s\*{3}$)'
```

I can't seem to get the greedyness or optional groups to work together.  http://pythex.org/ has been very helpful to this point.

Also, I tried capturing the asterisks '(*{3})' and then determining if section or sub section based on the number of groups found.

```
sectionRegex=re.compile('(\*{3})'
m=re.search(sectionRegex)
  if m.lastindex == 0:
       sectionName = re.sub(sectionRegex,'',line) 
       #Set a section flag
  if m.lastindex ==1:
       sectionName = re.sub(sectionRegex,''line)
       #Set a sub section flag.
```

**THANKS**
Maybe I'm going at this totally wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

**Latest Update**
I've been playing with Pythex, answers, and other research.  I'm now spending more time capturing the words:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

and counting the number of asterisk matches to determine "level".  I am still searching for a single regexp to match the two - three "groups".  May not exist.

Thanks.

Comment: you don't need a regex, str.startswith will do what you want although if both can have 2 spaces with three ***  you are kind of screwed

Comment: How do you distinguish between 0-2 spaces and 2+ spaces?

Comment: Can you add a sample of other lines that may appear as right now `line.lstrip().replace("***","")` will do exactly what you seem to want

Comment: strip and replace commands don't yield the section type (main section vs sub section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **QUESTION 1**: Is there a python regexp with capture groups that would 
>   let me access the section/sub section names as a capture group?
>
> > a single regexp to match the two - three "groups". May not exist

Yes, it can be done. We can decomposs the conditions as the following tree:

- <kbd>Start of line</kbd> **+** <kbd>0 to 2 spaces</kbd>
- Any of the 2 alternations:

  1. `***` **+** <kbd>Any text</kbd><sup>[group 1]</sup>
  2. <kbd>1+ spaces</kbd> **+** `***` **+** <kbd>Any text</kbd><sup>[group 2]</sup>
- `***`<sup>(optional)</sup> **+** <kbd>End of line</kbd>

And the above tree can be expressed with the pattern:

```
^[ ]{0,2}(?:[*]{3}(.*?)|[ ]+[*]{3}(.*?))(?:[*]{3})?$
```

- [regex101 DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mV0gN4/1)

Notice the *Section* and *Sub-Section* are being captured by different groups (<sup>[group 1]</sup> and <sup>[group 2]</sup> respectively). They both use the same syntax `.*?`, both with a [lazy quantifier (the extra "?")](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) to allow the optional `"***"` at the end to match.

---

> **QUESTION 2**: How would the regexp groups allow me to ID section 
>   or sub section (possibly based on the number of /content in a match.group)?

The above regex captures *Sections* only in group 1, and *Sub-Sections* only in group 2. And to make it easier to identify in the code, I'll use [`(?P<named> groups)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) and retrieve the captures with **[`.groupdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groupdict)**.

#### Code:

```python
import re

data = """  *** Section with no sub section
  *** Section with sub section ***
           *** Sub Section ***
  *** Another section"""

pattern = r'^[ ]{0,2}(?:[*]{3}[ ]?(?P<Section>.*?)|[ ]+[*]{3}[ ]?(?P<SubSection>.*?))(?:[ ]?[*]{3})?$'
regex = re.compile(pattern, re.M)

for match in regex.finditer(data):
    print(match.groupdict())

''' OUTPUT:
{'Section': 'Section with no sub section', 'SubSection': None}
{'Section': 'Section with sub section', 'SubSection': None}
{'Section': None, 'SubSection': 'Sub Section'}
{'Section': 'Another section', 'SubSection': None}
'''
```

- [ideone DEMO](http://ideone.com/9fRpY6)

Instead of printing the dict, to reference each *Section*/*Subsection*, you can use one of the following:

```
match.group("Section")
match.group(1)
match.group("SubSection")
match.group(2)
```

Comment: Great detail, very helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean 3+ spaces for the subsections, you can do something like this:

```
import re

data = '''
  *** Section with no sub section
*** Section with sub section ***
           *** Sub Section ***
 *** Another section
'''

pattern = r'(?:(^ {0,2}\*{3}.*\*{3} *$)|(^ {0,2}\*{3}.*)|(^ *\*{3}.*\*{3} *$))'

regex = re.compile(pattern, re.M)
print regex.findall(data)
```

This will give you groups as follows:

```
[('', '  *** Section with no sub section', ''),
 ('*** Section with sub section ***', '', ''),
 ('', '', '           *** Sub Section ***'),
 ('', ' *** Another section', '')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The regexp:

```
(^\s+)(\*{3})([a-zA-Z\s]+)(\*{3})*
```

Captures 3 or 4 groups as described below.

```
Group 0: "(^\s+)" Captures whitespace
Group 1: "(\*{3})" captures '***'
Group 2:"([a-zA-Z\s]+)" captures alpha characters and spaces
Group 3: "(\*{3})*" captures 0 or or more occurrences of "***"
```